# How can I justify the existence of this combination dragon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons, monster-design

I'd like to have in my campaign a unique dragon that combines the abilities of a [black dragon](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDrtoDw.html#black-dragon) and a [red dragon](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDrtoDw.html#red-dragon) (*Monster Manual* 70–2 and 75–7, respectively) with those of a beast dragon (*Dragon* #321 50–1).

- Are there character options that enable a PC or NPC to *create* such a monster? That is, are there feats, magic items, prestige class class features, skill uses, spells, or whatever that enable a PC or NPC to manufacture hybrid monsters like this?
- Is there a game-legal way for such a monster to exist *without* deliberate outside interference? That is, could a dragon have to it applied a series of templates lead to such a combination, or could a dragon take class levels that give it the semblance of being a combination of these creatures?

Comment: Are you playing in any particular published setting? I would expect lore support for the concept might vary depending on setting.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.stackexchange.com Phaede. This site is different ffrom a normal forum board. You should make an objective question that can be answered without much subjectivity. Please [take the tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn how to use this site. Also, browse some questions (with high vote count) to see what kind of posts are desired here.

Comment: The question will be probably closed for editting, so we can whip it in shape. Use the comments section to ask for assistance. The first thing you should do is to define exactly what you want.

Comment: I edited this *a lot*. I hope that's okay. I *think* I preserved the basic sense of the question, but, please, feel free to edit it further or rollback if it's no longer asking the question you want answered. I did my best to figure some things out (like the *actual* location of the beast dragon), but I think I speak for all readers when I ask *What purpose is this creature serving in the campaign that requires it to be this weird amalgam dragon?*

Comment: @hey-i-can-chan With your edit I think this could be reopened. But, I would swap the bullet point order. It appears that OP is asking the "creation" part out of a misunderstanding of how these creatures exist in the world and is simply trying to grasp that (I could be wrong) which makes it secondary to the main point of the question being "can this thing exist". (sorry that was kinda rambly, hopefully it's understandable)

Comment: @Ben-Jamin I, too, think it's probably valid for reopening *now*, but I'd like folks to wait until the asker approves the edit—it *is* a *severe* edit that kinda rewrites the entire question, after all. It seemed to me that the issues as presented in the question *now* was the order the issues were brought up in the original, so I felt it best to preserve the order, but if you want to edit the question further to swap the bullets, that's cool and I've got your back.

Comment: isn't there one "w-g-r-b-u"-dragon hybrid called tiamat already? mother of all dragons? ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Use a Half-Red-Dragon, Half-Black-Dragon Beast Dragon

Or, if you prefer, a Half-Black-Dragon, Half-Red-Dragon Beast Dragon.  Or, since there's a way to get Half-Beast-Dragons, like the article says are common, maybe combinations with that, too (though they get two fewer immunities).  In any case, you get a creature with all three dragon bits and some powers stemming from each.  Bonus points if you make a Half-Red-Dragon, Half-Black-Dragon, Half-Beast-Dragon nine-headed hydra.

This lets you create a creature with some of the abilities of all three, and potentially all the abilities of one of them.  Also a truly massive strength score and immunity to, in the titular case, fire, acid, cold, and electricity.

Such a creature can naturally come to exist without outside intervention through normal draconic baby-making, albeit between unusual parents, or perhaps born in an unusual location (a Beast dragon born to a Red dragon and a Black dragon would work, for example), or something else.  In any case, the template is certainly clear that it *can* be applied.

#### Getting the Titular Dragon as a PC/NPC

All of the Dragons involved, as well as the Half-Dragon template, provide level adjustment should you wish to use them as a player or acquire them via features that are LA-limited.  Specifically, a PC may play a level 0 Half-Red-Dragon, Half-Black-Dragon Beast Dragon Wyrmling at 15th ECL.

A PC may also acquire such a creature as a cohort with a leadership score of 21 and the Leadership feat, or as a follower with a leadership score of 71 and Legendary Commander.  Older versions can also be gained as a cohort, but not as a follower.

A PC may use *True Mind Switch*, *Dominate Monster*, or other magics to gain access to such a creature given the existence of such a creature.

A PC may use Epic Spellcasting and the Summon seed to summon such a creature and press it into indefinite service, even up to the Great Wyrm variety.

An Antipaladin may also follow the rules in the Draconomicon to gain such a creature as a special mount, as could a paladin were such a creature subjected to a *helm of opposite alignment*.

You can create a duplicate of such a creature by exposing one to a *mirror of opposition*, though the duplicate ceases to exist as soon as itself or the original is defeated so careful measures must be taken to ensure neither case occurs.

A PC can *manufacture* such a being in a variety of ways.  The first is via *Similacrum*, which allows you to create partially-real versions of any creature imaginable.  While it might seem like you first need a piece of the creature, such a piece should be available in your spell component pouch.  The ruby involved, however, costs 100gp per HD the simulacrum will possess, which is half the HD of the creature being mimicked, and you can only mimic a creature whose HD is less than twice your caster level.

A 78 HD Half-Red-Dragon, Half-Black-Dragon Great Wyrm Beast Dragon (the minimum for the mimic to itself function as a Great Wyrm specimen) costs 7,800 gp (and an equal amount of XP) to create and requires caster level 39.

You can also create such a creature with the *Conjure*, *Life*, and *Fortify* epic spell seeds, which allow you to create most any creature.

You can create a mechanical creature, an effigy, via Craft Construct, as detailed in Complete Arcane, but effigy creatures lose all special qualities and most special abilities, and so aren't really very appropriate.

You can use a Sarruhk from serpent kingdoms to grant the various abilities of a red, black, and/or beast dragon onto any Scaled One, like another dragon or a Kobold or a tiny viper.  This way lies the path to madness, though.

Comment: So much better, thank you all so much. I hadnt thought of the Hydra idea and just stacking Half-Dragon templates was something I thought of but didnt know if I could do.  Im going to talk to my DM about this creature and see what we can do.  This is the best I could ever hope for.

Comment: @PhaedeS. Thanks!  If this post solved your problem, remember you can click the green checkmark on it to mark it as accepted :)  Good luck with your game!